# Find a closed form for the recurrence $g(n+2)= 5g(n+1)-5g(n)+g(n-1)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

More specifically use the initial values $g(1)=0, \ g(2)=0, \ g(3)=1$. I know several methods for solving order two recurrences but this being an order three would include having to evaluate a cubic polynomial and then solve for the initial values.
The first several numbers are $0,0,1,5,20,76...$
Is there a nice shortcut of a method?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation#Characteristic_equation_and_roots) for the standard approach to solving a linear recurrence like this one. But I think what you describe ([undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)) is a quicker method.

Comment: It is easy to see $1$ is a root of the auxiliary cubic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest method is definitely to use [sage](https://sagemath.org) or some other computer algebra system. I solve a lot of recurrences, and my sage [startup script](https://github.com/HallaSurvivor/dotfiles/blob/master/init.sage) makes it particularly easy for me. In particular:

```
sage: eqn = T(n+3) == 5*T(n+2) - 5*T(n+1) + T(n)
sage: rsolve(eqn,n,[0,0,1])
1/12*(-sqrt(3) + 2)^n*(sqrt(3) + 3) - 1/12*(sqrt(3) + 2)^n*(sqrt(3) - 3) - 1/2
```

We can, of course, display this more nicely using the `latex` command:

$$
\frac{1}{12} \, {\left(-\sqrt{3} + 2\right)}^{n} {\left(\sqrt{3} + 3\right)} - \frac{1}{12} \, {\left(\sqrt{3} + 2\right)}^{n} {\left(\sqrt{3} - 3\right)} - \frac{1}{2}
$$

---

Of course, there's something to be said for solving these kinds of equations by hand. I'm personally partial to [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for this task, but there's lots of approaches. I don't know of any "shortcuts" to do these kinds of problem in general. Much like taking derivatives of nested functions, the process is tedious, but not hard:

We start by writing $G(z) = \sum g_n z^n$, then by multiplying your recurrence by $z^n$ and summing we find

$$
\frac{G - g_2 z^2 - g_1 z - g_0}{z^3} = 
5 \frac{G - g_1 z - g_0}{z^2} - 5 \frac{G - g_0}{z} + G
$$

But we know $g_0 = 1$, $g_1 = g_2 = 0$. So we can plug these in and solve for

$$
G = \frac{1 - 5z + 5z^2}{1 - 5z + 5z^2 - z^3}
$$

then using partial fractions, we can write this as

$$
G = 
\frac{\sqrt{3} + 3}{12} \frac{1}{1 - (- \sqrt{3} + 2) z} - 
\frac{\sqrt{3} - 3}{12} \frac{1}{1 - (  \sqrt{3} + 2) z} - 
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-z}.
$$

Then using the formula for a geometric series on the right hand side, and remembering
$g(n)$ is the coefficient of $z^n$ in $G$, we can get the formula that sage got for us earlier.

If you want to read more about this technique, you might be interested in the excellent book [*generatingfunctionology*](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html) which is available for free at that link!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @BenjaminWarren -- Happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question you should mark it as such so that other users know where to spend their time